# How do I make a layout half transparent?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a scrollable tab where in the container main .Iam making an image blur

[image: this is what i am getting]

But I want to display half blur and half coloured

[image: here]

In the second one I want to display the blur background and in other half the material design colour "With no alpha"

How to set this
here is my container main code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.union.front1.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:background="#060606">
            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:theme="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="#000"
                style="@style/AppTheme.my"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my fragment code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.union.front1.Album"
    android:background="#e5060606">

    <es.guiguegon.sineview.SineView
        android:id="@+id/sine_view_album"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:sv_sine_alpha="1"
        app:sv_sine_amplitude="25dp"
        app:sv_sine_animation_time_millis="2000"
        app:sv_sine_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:sv_sine_periods_to_show="2"
        app:sv_sine_phase="1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How I can set half the layout as transparent and half as strong color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error i was doing is I placed my imageview below the viewpager that means the image view layer will come over the view pager layer so I placed the imageview layer above the viewpager layer in this way I dont have to set the alpha of the image and and it will show the image in the background.When i use the strong colour in my fragment it will remain strong as i am not using alpha for the image view `

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.union.front1.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />`
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager"

    android:background="#060606"
    >
    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#000"
        style="@style/AppTheme.my"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"


        />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```